# Create navigation property to view-based entity without foreign key

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm working on an Entity Framework application which uses the Microsoft `AspNetUsers` table to store logins. However this app already made the dubious decision of storing additional details about users not in `AspNetUsers`, but in a couple other tables that each have an `AspNetUsersID`.

So I've created a view, `UserDetail`, which is a union of these other tables, including `AspNetUsersID`, and mapped it to an entity. But of course, I can't define a FK on this view.

Is it possible to create a navigation property, `AspNetUser.UserDetails` which I can then load via eager loading, without a second trip to the database? I've tried the following code (rest of the partial class is auto-generated using DB to POCO generator):

```cs
public partial class AspNetUser
{
    public virtual ICollection<UserDetail> UserDetails { get; set; }
}

internal partial class AspNetUserConfiguration
{
    partial void InitializePartial()
    {
        HasMany(a => a.UserDetails).WithRequired().Map(MapUserDetail);
    }

    private void MapUserDetail(ForeignKeyAssociationMappingConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapKey("AspNetUsersID");
    }
}
```

which results in:

> AspNetUsersID: Name: Each property name in a type must be unique. Property name 'AspNetUsersID' is already defined.

Is there any way to accomplish what I'm trying to do, or does EF just not support this type of navigation property?